# Is exposing class and method names in the URL unsecure?

Tags: php, algorithm, performance, security

I don't use any famous framework and I've created my own one. It is actually kind of a advanced MVC. Anyway, Its routing is totally different than other frameworks. I mean, there isn't any file named *route* containing all routes. It will call the needed class and function automatically based on the URL. For example:

```
http://example.com/classname/methodname/arg1/arg2
```

URL above calls this script by using `autoloader`:

```
class classname{

    public function methodname() {

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

See? Everyone will know the name of class or method in my script. My question is, is that secure enough? Or is there something particular that I should know?

Comment: What if I call `/DateTime/createFromFormat/Y-m-d/2017-06-06`. What if I call `CommonEncryptionLibrary/encrypt/some-investigative-payload`. In short, allowing people to arbitrarily call methods on classes is not a good idea. Best to whitelist what controller actions get called in a routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your framework allows arbitrary classes and function to be invoked, this means you effectively build a remote shell with a web interface. In other words: maximum insecure.

Likewise, if your application also allows file uploads, a malicious user might be able to upload their own PHP classes and then invoke it from your URLs. Without further details about your framework, it's hard to say. But you probably want to whitelist what can be called this way.

Even if the framework has some protection measures to control what code can be called, I am not a friend of leaking implementation details like this to the public. You tied your public API to a specific implementation with this. That will make it harder to change the code while maintaining the same API for clients to call.

Comment: I see, but you know, my framework before calling everything, checks class and method existing, otherwise, it redirects the user to the 404 page. Do you still believe my framework is bad?

Comment: @stack yes, I do. See my last paragraph. Also, checking if a class exists does not prevent *arbitrary execution*. Whitelisting does.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you ... upvote. Anyway, Currently I don't have free time to change the whole routing structure. Do you have any suggestion for my current algorithm?

Comment: @stack why don't you just use an existing router, like https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute

Comment: Based on a glance, I figured it out changing the whole my algorithm is more easy than implementing *(using in my project)* the router you suggested.

Comment: @stack maybe it's *easier* but it's apparently also much more insecure and coupling the implementation to the API.

Comment: Ok, and my last comment, what do you thing about putting a converter on the way of invoking? I mean defining an array contains class names and what should be written in the URL? Like: `$converter= ['whatInTheUrl' => 'realClassName']`, And I invoke the class like this `$converter['whatInTheUrl']`. Then nobody won't know the name of class.

Comment: @stack yes, a whitelist. That would be much more secure and also hide the implementation from the public API. On a sidenote: that map is effectively a "routes file" then.

Comment: Ok I will set a whitelist up in my fromework. Just what you mean  *public API*? I don't show the implementation nowhere.

Comment: @stack If I want to interface with your application, I do so via the URLs. That is why the URLs are the Public API. It's public because anyone can use it. Your URLs are based on the HTTP protocol. But they expose details about the implementation because I can call PHP classes and methods in it. So instead of just calling `example.com/users?location=somewhere` (which has no details about the language fulfilling the request), your urls ask for `example.com/Users/findByLocation/somewhere` which directly uses the underlying implementation. if you change the implementation, you'll change the url.

Comment: @stack the urls above are just an example. But you get the idea. As long as the URLs map directly onto classes and methods, you are exposing the implementation. If the code changes, the urls need to change as well.